# How to pass opacity variable to function draw()

Tags: jquery, canvas

The console confirms to me that opacity propagates correctly the values between 0 and 1. I searched for hours how to take this variable to function draw() to change the value of transparency of a rectangle. I would appreciate any guidance.

```
$(document).ready( function() {         
        $('.demo').each( function() {
         $(this).minicolors({
        opacity: true,                  
        change: function(hex, opacity) {                        
         console.log(hex + ' - ' + opacity);

                      draw();                       

                   },

                theme: 'bootstrap'
            });                
        });

    });
```

// I need to transfer opacity var to opacityVar(?)

```
function draw() {

     ctx.save();        
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.rect(0, 10, 200, 320); 
     ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(77,225,77, MyOpacity'; 

      ctx.fill();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it like

```
//draw accepts opacity as a parameter
function draw(opacity) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0, 10, 200, 320);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(77,225,77, ' + opacity + ')';
    ctx.fill();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.demo').each(function () {
        $(this).minicolors({
            opacity: true,
            change: function (hex, opacity) {
                console.log(hex + ' - ' + opacity);
                //pass opacity as the argument
                draw(opacity);
            },
            theme: 'bootstrap'
        });
    });
});
```